# Swift Booleans not working: Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'BOOL' (aka 'Int32')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an iOS project that depends on several external dependencies (swift frameworks, objective C projects, and vanilla C). All of a sudden (with no code changes that I can see), the builds have begun failing, flagging errors:

[image]

I am on Xcode 11.3.1 with Swift 5.

This error persists even after reverting to an earlier revision of the project that was known to compile, and when attempting to build on a new machine with a completely fresh clone of the project.

I am at a complete loss at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've noticed for some reason my compiler version was set to Swift 4.2 in my Build Settings. Now the project builds....sort of. When I try to archive the project I still have the same problem, but a normal build with Product->Build works.

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this error in a small project as I have no idea what change caused it to begin happening.

Comment: Some *code* demonstrating the problem would be helpful – ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @MartinR Please see my edit, I've tried to reproduce in a smaller project to no avail.

Comment: Do a clean build (Cmd-Opt-Shift-K), delete all derived data and then restart Xcode.

Comment: Have you upgraded (or downgraded) any of you tools recently (like Xcode or Swift version, or any other tools you might use)? Code just don't fail to build like that. Something has changed and figuring out what might give you the best hint to solve this.

Comment: @koen I've been cleaning the build before most builds.

Comment: @rraphael The build is now working if I disable optimizations. Nothing major has changed in the tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to disable optimizations in the build settings (from "optimize for speed" to "no optimization").

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? Code that compiles differently depending on the optimization setting reflects a bug in Swift and needs to be reported to Apple.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it in a more isolated setting to no avail so far. I'll give it another shot tomorrow if I have time, but I suspect I won't be able to. The project is by far the most complex dependency-hell I've ever worked on so it is very difficult to pin down exactly what is causing the problem.